# Return two foreign ID's combined in a clause Where - Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

How can I do something like this on Rails:

```
Follow.where("user_id = ? AND forum_id = ?", current_user.id , params[:id])
```

I want to show the button follow when the user isn't following the forum, and hide when the user is already following. I googled 2 days straight and couldn't find any solution for this. Hope here I find a way to my solution. 
Thanks

Comment: Your `Follow.where` looks like perfectly valid Rails code to me, [`exists?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-exists-3F) might be a better call but I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: In what way does your suggested code not work?

Comment: i coudn't answer my question( have to wait 8 hours ), but the code does work, the problem was with updating cache I think, because on rails console was showing the opposite. Thanks guys